# create new sqlite database after another one

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app that it can create several database by enter db name in edit text by user and it show on a list view. My problem: I can not add more than one database after create it until close app and reopen it. Thanks for any help!

```
public static final File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/memoryplus");
public static final File DB_NAME = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + MainActivity.dbName + ".db");

Button btnAdd = (Button)dlc.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dbName=ed.getText().toString();

                    myDb=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                    boolean result= myDb.insertData(null,null);

                    FilesInFolder.clear();
                    Adapter.clear();
                    RefreshListView();
                    ed.setText("");

                    myDb.close();

                    dlc.dismiss();


                }
            });
```

Comment: why do you want to create more than one db? i really cant think of a use case for this... unless ones for testing and another is for prod... but then you are also creating a sqlite... so idk. seems silly and very unproductive.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple databases and have them open at the same time.

Here's an example that creates (and opens) 20 databases and then lists the tables therein (1 table, the same added to each).

It creates/opens 10 using a **Database Helper** (i.e. a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper class) and 10 without using a **DatbaseHelper**.

**As such it has 20 concurrent open databases.**

**DBHelper.java** The Database Helper :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_EMAIL = "_email";
    public static final String MYTABLE_COL_PASSWORD = "_password";

    static final String crtsql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_MYTABLE + "(" +
            MYTABLE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            MYTABLE_COL_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            MYTABLE_COL_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +
            MYTABLE_COL_PASSWORD + " TEXT " +
            ")";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name) {
        super(context, name, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(crtsql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    }

    public void logTables() {
        Cursor csr = mDB.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBHLPRTABLES",csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** The invoking/using activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<SQLiteDatabase> mDatabaseList;
    ArrayList<DBHelper> mDBHelperList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDatabaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDBHelperList = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i=0;i < 10; i++) {
            mDatabaseList.add(createSQLiteDatabase("mydb" + String.valueOf(i)));
            mDBHelperList.add(new DBHelper(this, "dbmine" + String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        for (SQLiteDatabase db: mDatabaseList) {
            Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d("TABLES",csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
        }

        for (DBHelper dbhlpr: mDBHelperList) {
            dbhlpr.logTables();
        }
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase createSQLiteDatabase(String dbname) {
        File dbpath = getDatabasePath(dbname);
        File dir = new File(dbpath.getParent());
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db =  SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbpath,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mycolumn TEXT)");
        return db;
    }
}
```

- This loops 10 times. For each loop it

  - Opens or creates a database **mydb**? (where ? is 0 then 1 ..... 9) adding the **SQliteDatabase** object to the **mDatabaseList** ArrayList.
  - Instantiates an instance of the **DBHelper** class with a database name of **dbmine**? (where ? is 0 then 1 ..... 9) (which effectively opens or creates the database due to **`mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();`**), the **DBHelper** instance is added to the **mDBHelperList** ArrayList.
- It then loops through the **mDatabaseList** (10 databases) running a query against each that lists the names from the **sqlite_master** table.
- It then does much the same for the **mDBHelperList** (calls the **`logTables`** method).

### Device Explorer shows :-

[image]

### The Log  Shows :-

```
09-19 22:06:49.503 1820-1820/? D/TABLES: android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
09-19 22:06:49.507 1820-1820/? D/TABLES: android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
    android_metadata
    mytable
09-19 22:06:49.507 1820-1820/? D/DBHLPRTABLES: android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
09-19 22:06:49.511 1820-1820/? D/DBHLPRTABLES: android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
    android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
09-19 22:06:49.519 1820-1820/? D/DBHLPRTABLES: android_metadata
    mytable
    sqlite_autoindex_mytable_1
```

Comment: thank's a lot. but i want add db files manually by enter them names in edit text, not automatically by loop.

Comment: @AhmadSilentman the loop is just to show the principle, all you have to do is take the 1 relevant line from the loop and place it into your `onClick` method (obviously adapting the creation methodology which suits).